# How to convert xml response into json and get the value from that json in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, xml

How can I convert the xml responce into json and get the particular value from it.
Here is what I tried :

```
response = HTTParty.post 'http://api.ontraport.com/cdata.php',
{:body => {:appid => 'YeBz0j1',:key => 'NqweN80',:reqType => "fetch_sequences" }}
response = Hash.from_xml(response).to_json
render json: (response)
```

And I am getting the result:

```
{"result":{"sequence":[{"id":"148"},{"id":"211"},"!Kyle OP Test","(SS) AnikSIB - 1 Hour Reminder","(SS) AnikSIB - 5 minutes Reminder","(SS) AnikSIB - Attended After Over"]}}
```

But I if write `render json: (response['result'])` then my output is wrong it just print `result` as output.And how can I use `JSON.pretty_generate` for pretty print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should deal with the hash in the first place:

```
response = Hash.from_xml(response)
```

*NB:* in your code `Hash.from_xml(response).to_json` had produced the string, containing the respective json. Now you can:

```
render json: response['result']
```

One does not need to explicitly call `to_json` in `render`, the engine will convert it on it’s own.

*Sidenote:* `responce['result']` printing `"result"` string is a funny side-effect of a call to `String#[]` method. After `to_json`, `response` contains the *string* with a hash converted to json, and since there is an occurrence of `"result"` substring in it, the substring is printed out.